# Author name is not displaying on shared post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

We have 2 articles:

- A -
  http://familyshare.com/one-little-girl-learns-the-true-meaning-of-delete
- B - http://familyshare.com/how-to-stay-open-hearted-in-a-world-with-so-much-turmoil

Both have fb share button (using custom js fb api)

```
<meta name="author" content="AUTHOR NAME">
```

...

```
 <a class="social-facebook" rel="nofollow" data-event="facebook/1/19803/19803/popup/580/386" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://familyshare.com/one-little-girl-learns-the-true-meaning-of-delete&amp;t=One%20little%20girl%20learns%20the%20true%20meaning%20of%20delete">Share</a>
```

They have the same html structure

Both shared well accept one thing. There is no author's name for shared article "A" (only site name). For article "B" it's okay:

SITE_NAME | BY AUTHOR NAME

Comment: Could you create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. This will significantly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffamilyshare.com%2Fone-little-girl-learns-the-true-meaning-of-delete – pay attention to the warning. As for the second URL, that is not even public, so neither can we test it ourselves, nor could you expect any predictable share behavior on FB because of that.